# Javascript won't filter eBay API results by price/listing type

Tags: javascript, html, json, ebay-api

After following eBay's API guidelines for displaying fixed price items that fall within a specified price range, results are still showing auction based items of varying prices outside the range. I followed their tutorial word for word, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Code:

```
<div id="api"></div>

<script>
function _cb_findItemsByKeywords(root)
{
  var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
  var html = [];
  html.push('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"><tbody>');

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)  
  {
    var item     = items[i];
    var title    = item.title;
    var pic      = item.galleryURL;
    var viewitem = item.viewItemURL;
    if (null != title && null != viewitem)
    {
      html.push(
        '<tr id="api_microposts"><td>'
         + '<img src="' + pic + '" border="0" width="190">' + '<a href="' + viewitem + '" target="_blank">' + title + 
         '</a></td></tr>');
    }
  }
  html.push('</tbody></table>');
  document.getElementById("api").innerHTML = html.join("");

// Create a JavaScript array of the item filters you want to use in your request
var filterarray = [
  {"name":"MaxPrice",
   "value":"500",
   "paramName":"Currency",
   "paramValue":"USD"},
   {"name":"MinPrice",
   "value":"200",
   "paramName":"Currency",
   "paramValue":"USD"},
  {"name":"FreeShippingOnly",
   "value":"true",
   "paramName":"",
   "paramValue":""},
  {"name":"ListingType",
   "value":["FixedPrice"],
   "paramName":"",
   "paramValue":""},
  ];


// Define global variable for the URL filter
var urlfilter = "";


// Generates an indexed URL snippet from the array of item filters
function  buildURLArray() {
  // Iterate through each filter in the array
  for(var i=0; i<filterarray.length; i++) {
    //Index each item filter in filterarray
    var itemfilter = filterarray[i];
    // Iterate through each parameter in each item filter
    for(var index in itemfilter) {
      // Check to see if the parameter has a value (some don't)
      if (itemfilter[index] !== "") {
        if (itemfilter[index] instanceof Array) {
          for(var r=0; r<itemfilter[index].length; r++) {
          var value = itemfilter[index][r];
          urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "\(" + r + "\)=" + value ;
          }
        }
        else {
          urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "=" + itemfilter[index];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}  // End buildURLArray() function

// Execute the function to build the URL filter
buildURLArray(filterarray);

url += urlfilter;



}
</script>


<!--
Use the value of your appid for the appid parameter below.
-->
<script src=http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=*App ID*&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=iphone%205%2016gb%20unlocked&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The specifications come from [this page](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/Finding/CallRef/extra/fndItmsByKywrdsRqst.tmFltr.nm.html).  I would tackle this problem in two steps:

Check to see if you get the same results even if you comment out this line:

```
    url += urlfilter;
```

If that happens then your problem is the way you make the request and the parameters you set are not yet relevant.  If it does change then the request is going through well enough and you need to fiddle what you pass in.

In that case the parameters need some fiddling.  If you are getting any results then one issue could be with the *ListingType* filter.  The specifications say that ListingType takes a string OR can take multiple values.  It might be that you want to use:

```
    {"name":"ListingType",
    "value": "FixedPrice",
    "paramName":"",
    "paramValue":""}
```

Comment: Still getting unfiltered results even after using the syntax above. I'm going to look into the specs some more and see if there's something else I might be doing wrong.